# MVC6 Taghelper Select Control with Selected Item in indexed model

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am trying to set the selected value of a select control based on a model in an indexed situation.  I have the following code -

```
<select asp-for="Items.Details[i].One"
    asp-items="Utility.DropdownListItems(date, Model.Items.Details[i].One)">
</select>
```

I am setting the selected item in the Utility that returns the SelectList, and would expect that to set the selected item of the drop down, but that doesn't work.  If I inspect the option elements, none have the selected tag.
I know there was an issue with indexed data in previous iterations of Mvc HtmlHelpers.  Does anyone know if this was resolved in MVC6?

Comment: see Using Option Groups with the Select TagHelper in MVC 6 http://ow.ly/Sa392

Answer (score 1):

For both HTML and tag helpers, generated `<option>` elements are selected based on the expression value (`Item.Details[i].One` in your case). `IsSelected` from the select list matters only if the expression value is `null` i.e. in the Create case.

We have corrected a number of issues related to indexed data in MVC 6. Please file an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues if something is still not working.